# How to turn a list of Polars expressions into one multi-column expression?

Tags: expression, python-polars

Let's say I've constructed a list of expressions

```py
# polars==0.19.2
import polars as pl


N = 5
powers_list = [(pl.col("a") ** i).alias(f"a{i}") for i in range(1, N + 1)]
df = pl.DataFrame({"a": [0, 1, 2]})
```

To apply an operation to each expression of the list I have to loop through its elements

```py
df = df.with_columns([expr + 10 for expr in powers_list])
print(df)
```

But it would be more convenient to do something like this

```py
powers_expr = pl.to_expr(powers_list)  # this is a fake function
df = df.with_columns(powers_expr + 10)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
powers_expr =pl.col([x.meta.output_name() for x in powers_list])
```

or you can make it a function and monkey patch it in like

```
def toexpr(list_in):
    return pl.col([x.meta.output_name() for x in list_in])
pl.to_expr=toexpr
### Now this works
powers_expr = pl.to_expr(powers_list)
```

then

```
df.with_columns(powers_expr + 10)
shape: (3, 6)
┌─────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┐
│ a   ┆ a1   ┆ a2   ┆ a3   ┆ a4   ┆ a5   │
│ --- ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ i64 ┆ f64  ┆ f64  ┆ f64  ┆ f64  ┆ f64  │
╞═════╪══════╪══════╪══════╪══════╪══════╡
│ 0   ┆ 20.0 ┆ 20.0 ┆ 20.0 ┆ 20.0 ┆ 20.0 │
│ 1   ┆ 21.0 ┆ 21.0 ┆ 21.0 ┆ 21.0 ┆ 21.0 │
│ 2   ┆ 22.0 ┆ 24.0 ┆ 28.0 ┆ 36.0 ┆ 52.0 │
└─────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┘
```

As a side note, there's the new [column selector](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/selectors.html) interface that gives more extensible column selection ability

Comment: Nice! But it would be nicer, if Polars had an obvious way to do this. Multi-column expressions are just syntactic sugar anyway.

Comment: I suppose the built in way would be to give your columns a name with a pattern then use regex